# How to display element randomly from another url?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to randomly display three divs (of the same class ".post-content") from a specific url.

I can display contents of a div from another url (with consent) using the following code, but it lacks the randomisation I need:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var contentURI= 'http://www.example.com/ .post-content';
    $('#response').load('grabber.php?url='+ contentURI);
});
</script>

<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>

<div id="response"></div>
```

*EDIT* This currently outputs a url with just the one div of that class. I need it to output x3 divs of the same class at random.

My skills are somewhat lacking to mash other code I've found into one concise code. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the return value from grabber.php?

Comment: I've managed to get the code working on a page where there is only one occurrence of the class. Therefore, it displays the contents of that one class that contains text.

Comment: Can you please edit your Post an add the output? Also what exactly is your problem? Randomise the output or getting more than one element?

Comment: I've updated the OP. Think of it like this... I have an article and I want to effectively advertise x3 other articles (at random) at the bottom of the page. Other articles are summarised on a seperate url within the website, and I want to pull these divs (of the same class) at random to display.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

JQuery

```
$.get("https://www.example.com", function(data) {
    var $quotes = $(data).find(".container-articles-5"),
      count = $quotes.length,
      $random = function() {
        return $quotes.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * count));
      };
    $(".blog-ad-1").append($random);
});
```

HTML

```
<aside class="blog-ad-4">
    <div class="blog-ad-5">
      <div class="blog-ad-3">
        <div class="blog-ad-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-ad-3">
        <div class="blog-ad-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-ad-3">
        <div class="blog-ad-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```